# Stupid Batch File Behavior. Tries to execute comments

Tags: batch-file

I have tried prefixing lines with semicolons, 'REM', etc.. but no matter what when I run my batch file I keep getting "unknown command REM whatever"

Comment: Please give details of your environment. `REM` is recognised by the Windows XP command shell (cmd), but obviously you are using something different.

Comment: There's not much code to give. "REM test"
It is not recognized, and it is windows vista. I simply get "rem" output back to my console.

If I put ":: test" and execute it I get back "Test".

If I put "; test" it recursively executes itself

Comment: You sould post your code and details about your environment, as other said

Comment: I did post my code. It is a line that begins with REM and ends with some text. ANd then another line that looks the same (theyre just comments?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> "REM test" It is not recognized, and it is windows vista. I simply get "rem" output back to my console.

That's entirely normal behavior. Batch files are simply sequences of commands that are run one after another. So every line will get output to the console as if it were typed there.

```
H:\>echo rem test > test.cmd

H:\>test
```

yields the output

```
H:\>rem test
```

as if I typed `rem test` directly to the console.

You can suppress this by either prefixing the line with `@`:

```
@rem test
```

or by including `echo off` in the batch file:

```
@echo off
rem test
```

> If I put ":: test" and execute it I get back "Test".

Can't reproduce here.

> If I put "; test" it recursively executes itself

A semicolon at the start of the line seemingly gets ignored.

Comment: That was it! Sounds familiar too.

Answer (score 4):

If you're talking about `cmd.exe` batch files under Windows, you can use:

```
rem this method or
:: this method.
```

For `bash` and a lot of other UNIX-type shells, you use:

```
# this method.
```

I'm pretty certain you're not using `cmd.exe` since that would give you an error like:

```
'rem' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

rather then:

```
Unknown command ...
```

If you *are* using a UNIX-type shell, the `#` character is almost certainly what you're after. If you let us know exactly the shell you're using, we can probably help out further.

Comment: Keep in mind that `::` sometimes has unintended consequences within blocks. I've seen weird error messages about unknown drives but couldn't recreate them on recent versions of Windows.

Comment: I haven't seen any problem with that but then I don't write *huge* batch files. They mostly tend to have comments before a block to explain what's going on, and my blocks don't get that big before the contents of the blocks are refactored into a call statement.

Comment: Its cmd.exe, standard windows shell.
I put "REM test" (without quotes) into a file called test.bat, navigate to it and type "test" and press enter (within cmd.exe), I get "REM" output to my console and nothing else.

Comment: That's to be expected. Unless you prefix the command (`rem` in this case) with an `@` or turn off echoing the command to the console with `echo off` you will see every line in the batch file printed to the console. It doesn't do anything, though since it's a comment.

Answer (score 1):

you probably created an UNICODE file. These files contain 2 bytes header named BOM 
which is not shown by any editor but cmd attempts to execute them and fails.

To make sure this is indeed an issue: type any other command at the very beginning
of your file and see it throws the same error - for example @echo test

To fix it, just create a new plain text file and copy content of the original file there.
then remove the original file and replace it by the newly created one.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problems are line endings. Somehow Maven or the Jenkins pipeline running on a Linux machine changed the line endings from Windows style (`CR LF`) to Unix style (`LF`). Changing them back solves the issue for me.